# jQuery .text() method is not display index item value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I have a problem with the following code.
***HTML Code***

```html
<head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>          
    <div id="div1">
    <h1 id="array-item"></h1>
    <h3 id="index"></h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***test.js***

```js
var name=['muzaffarpur','madhepura','bihar','patana','delhi','munger'];
var addImg=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(slide, 1230);
});
function slide(){
  if(addImg<=5){
       $('#array-item').text(name[addImg]);
       $('#index').text(addImg);
       addImg++;
  }else addImg=0;
}
```

***EXPECTED OUTPUT***
When `addImg=0` it should display `muzaffarpur`, when `addImg=1` it should display `madhepura`, and so on. The output  comeing is different charectors of `muzaffarpur`, `ie` of first indexed value. 
***OUTPUT***

When `addImg=0` output is `m`, when `addImg=1` output is `a`, and so on. 
It should display indexed value, but it is displaying different charectors of first indexed item on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is reserved keyword in JavaScript. You mush not use it in a user defined way. 
[Reserved keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is happening as [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a reserved window variable name in javascript and is supposed to be a string. So, when you use:

```
var name=['muzaffarpur','madhepura','bihar','patana','delhi','munger'];
```

It explicitly cast it to a string like:

```
name = 'muzaffarpur,madhepura,bihar,patana,delhi,munger';
```

You can fix it by using a different array variable name like `arr`:

```js
var arr = ['muzaffarpur', 'madhepura', 'bihar', 'patana', 'delhi', 'munger'];
var addImg = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(slide, 1230);
});

function slide() {
  if (addImg <= 5) {
    $('#array-item').text(arr[addImg]);
    $('#index').text(addImg);
    addImg++;
  } else addImg = 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <h1 id="array-item"></h1>
  <h3 id="index"></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to What @palash said in his answer you can also have inside `document.ready()` event callback, this way you will never have it conflicting with the global `window.name` variable, take a way message **you have to make sure to name your variables so they don't conflict with other global variables**.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var name = ['muzaffarpur','madhepura','bihar','patana','delhi','munger'];
  var addImg=0;
  setInterval(slide, 1230);
  
  function slide(){
    if(addImg<=5){
         $('#array-item').text(name[addImg]);
         $('#index').text(addImg);
         addImg++;
    }else addImg=0;
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>          
    <div id="div1">
    <h1 id="array-item"></h1>
    <h3 id="index"></h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **name** is reserved in javascript. So, Please change it.

```
var name1 = ['muzaffarpur', 'madhepura', 'bihar', 'patana', 'delhi', 'munger'];

var addImg = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(slide, 1230);
});

function slide() {
    if (addImg <= 5) {
        jQuery('#array-item').text(name1[addImg]);
        jQuery('#index').text(addImg);
        addImg++;
    } else {
        addImg = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`name` is a reserved keyword in javascript

```js
var place_name = ['muzaffarpur', 'madhepura', 'bihar', 'patana', 'delhi', 'munger'];

var addImg = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(slide, 1230);
});

function slide() {
  if (addImg <= 5) {

    $('#array-item').text(place_name[addImg]);
    $('#index').text(addImg);
    addImg++;
  } else {
    addImg = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <h1 id="array-item"></h1>
  <h3 id="index"></h3>
</div>
```